# A boundary of p pixels going in a 2d numpy array using quick function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a (n_rows,m_cols) numpy array (The values of n_rows and m_cols are usually in a few hundred) of floats. I would like to make a strip (boundary if you like) around this but not change the size of the array.

How I want to do that is to make the first p rows, last p rows, first p cols and last p cols all = 0. (p is usually around five or ten)

I wondered if there was a quick way to do that.

Comment: ```x[:n] = [0] * n``` ?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np

# simulating your data
array = np.random.random(size=(100, 200))

# change to what you need
n_rows_head = 1
n_rows_tail = 2
n_cols_head = 2
n_cols_tail = 2

# new array
new_array = np.zeros_like(array)
new_array[n_rows_head:-n_rows_tail + 1, n_cols_head:-n_cols_tail + 1] = array[n_rows_head:-n_rows_tail + 1, n_cols_head:-n_cols_tail + 1]

# in place
array[:n_rows_head, :] = 0
array[-n_rows_tail:, :] = 0
array[:, :n_cols_head] = 0
array[:, -n_cols_tail:] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work only in if your using numpy:

```
y = numpy.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16,17,18],[19,20,21,22,23,24],[25,26,27,28,39,40],[41,42,43,44,45,46],[47,48,49,50,51,52]])


n=2
y[:n]=[0]
y[:,0:n]=[0]
y[-n:]=[0]
y[:,-n:]=[0]
```

Input:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
       [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 39, 40],
       [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46],
       [47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52]])
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 15, 16,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 21, 22,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 27, 28,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Slicing will work and is pretty fast. Though someone might be able to point you to a faster numpy method.

```py
import numpy as np

# --- Create a picture
m = 5
n = 10
picture = np.ones((m, n))


print(picture)
```

```
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

```py
p = 2
# --- Y perimeter
picture[:, 0:p] = 0
picture[:, -p:] = 0

# --- X perimeter
picture[:p, :] = 0
picture[-p:, :] = 0

print(picture)
```

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```